# How to use the animation correctly with class binding in vue?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to show a zoom effect and with an animation when I hover mouse over an image. I am using vue's class binding (which can be seen below after the problem definition). The problem is that I get the image zoomed with an animation but then the the zoom class gets called again and I see a zoomed image again if I don't move my mouse away from the image.

I have tried different animations but the same problem exists and transition also does not seem to work.

```html
<v-avatar>
      <img v-if="img" :src="img" :class="{ zoom: hover }" alt="" />
</v-avatar>
```

```css
@keyframes change {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.8) translateX(40px);
  }
}

.zoom {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: change 1s;
}
```

I expect to see the zoom behavior with an animation, but the zoom class should not be called again while the mouse is still over the avatar. So that would mean that I want the zoom effect to be shown only once, on a mouse hover.

Answer (score 1):

You should use css :hover selector not animation keyframes to achieve zoom on mouse over (hover)

```css
.image {
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.4s transform;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(2.8) translateX(40px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="image" />
```

Comment: It solves the problem defined in the question, but now as i move the mouse a little but i am still on the avatar, then the ```image``` class is called again and again with every movement. Can I somehow restrict this to be called only once on the first mouseover?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: So at the moment when i first hover on the avatar, the zoom and animation works, but as soon as I move the mouse a little over the avatar the behavior is repeating. I want to watch just the first hover and the rest of the movements should be ignored.

Comment: I want to show the zoom just once and that on the first hover

Comment: You are somewhat near. Actually I have an avatar and when I hover over it, I see the effect. but once i leave the avatar and go back to it again, it should be zoomable again. But for it to be zoomable, i should leave the avatar and then come back.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/febr60yg/ im still not really sure about what do you want achieve

Comment: I am thankful for your help, its a pity that explaining this problem without graphic display is getting tough, but we are getting closer. Can I use something like ```mousemove``` instead of ```mouseleave```. I think that would do the trick.

Comment: You can try `mouseover` too

Answer (score 0):

I used two classes in my stylesheet (which can also be used in the component itself instead).
One transition scales to 1.1 and the other scales to 1. This was because hovering off of the img was very jarring as it zoomed in smoothly but instantly returned to normal size off of img.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="./assets/flower.jpg"
@mouseover="hover = true"
@mouseleave="hover = false" :class="{zoomPicture: hover, zoomOutPicture: !hover}">
```

**Data inside the component:**

```
  data() {
    return {
      hover: false,
    }
  }
```

**CSS:**

```
.zoomPicture {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in;
    transition: .4s ease-in;
}

.zoomOutPicture {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in;
    transition: .3s ease-in;
}
```

So when the mouse isn't on the img, hover is false. This means the class "zoomOutPicture" is active, but won't change the img as it is already at the scale of 1.
Then when the user has their mouse over the img, hover becomes true and the image scales to 1.1. When they move the mouse off, hover becomes false and the img smoothly scales to 1 again, so it doesn't look as jarring as earlier now the zoomOutPicture class is used.